# In a Camunda embedded form, how do you specify the bound variable scope?

Tags: camunda

Within a user task, a segment of the embedded form markup is

```
...
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="reference">Reference</label>
    <input class="form-control"
           cam-variable-name="reference"
           cam-variable-type="String"
           name="reference" />
  </div>
  ...
```

On form entry, the `reference` field should be empty. On form submission, the associated Camunda process variable is populated with the reference text as a single `String` as expected.

Reading the Camunda manual, forums etc, there is no setting to specify the bound variable scope,

For this form field, I wish to use local variables (task scoped), not process instance scoped variables.

If process variables are used, if there is a following user task with a form using the same variable-name, that form field is populated with the previously entered value.

I understand that variables can be programmically reset and that I can use a different variable name but use of a local variable would avoid this.

Also, use of process variables results in an excessive number of variables as seen in

```
cockpit > running process instances > [process-name] > [instance GUID] > variables
```

Generally, unless the value is to be used later, form based variables have only relevance during form set-up and action processing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To set local variables in user forms, the easiest way is to define them in a task-listener creating the task. Then you can reference the variables with cam-variable-name in the form.

Have a look at this post for further details: https://forum.camunda.org/t/variables-in-parallel-process/1476/3

Comment: To clarify, the required local variables must be defined in the 'create' task listener using setVariableLocal().
Then, the embedded form will use the these local variables even if there are existing variables with the same name at process scope.
Also, other task listeners, eg 'complete', must use getVariableLocal().